# How to group values together when reading from a file in python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to redo old code for one of my projects, and I'm going to start with reading the list of values from a file instead of hardcoding it in. My python code looks like

```
f=open("readtimes.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents = f.read()
    print(list(contents))
```

and for simplicity lets say readtimes.txt is filled with "12.345, 23.456, 34.567"

The problem is when I print the list, it comes out as

```
['1', '2', '.', '3', '4', '5', ',', ' ',]
```

and so on. How do I get it to print

```
['12.345', '23.456', '34.567']'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `print(contents.split(','))`

Comment: Wow that was easier than expected, if you want to write this as an answer I'mm gladly accept it

Comment: Are there whitespaces between the commas?

Comment: yes, after each comma is a space

Comment: Let @DanielMesejo have the answer credit. His answer is thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @JacobIRR comment and taking into account the whitespaces, you could do the following:

```
content = "12.345, 23.456, 34.567"
result = [s.strip() for s in content.split(",")]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['12.345', '23.456', '34.567']
```

Or as an alternative:

```
content = "12.345, 23.456, 34.567"
result = list(map(str.strip, content.split(",")))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['12.345', '23.456', '34.567']
```

Comment: What I did was just split it at (", ") with that space after, and it worked just fine, thanks!